# How to make a container auto adjust its size according to its TextFormField child widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and am learning about TextFormFields. I have made an app that has a multiple line text field inside a container with some background. I want to increase the size of the container when user goes to the next line. How can I make the height of the container flexible? Or can I know when the user goes to the next line inside formTextField? Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MultiLineTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiLineTextField({super.key});

  @override
  State<MultiLineTextField> createState() => _MultiLineTextFieldState();
}

class _MultiLineTextFieldState extends State<MultiLineTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //Other widgets
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(47, 255, 255, 255),
              height: 75,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                  maxLines: null,
                  cursorHeight: 17,
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 0, 0, 0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    counterText: '',
                    labelText: 'Address',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {},
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The parent of this widget is scaffold -> materialapp.

I am running the code on simulator.

Comment: I think "height: 75" of your Container is problem. Could you remove and try first?

Comment: as you already have got an answer, here's some important reading to do on further understanding of constrains: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: I thought I had to hardcode the height as I got an unconstrained height error in the starting but your solution works. I will be reading up on constraints and layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Wai Han Ko answered to your post, you're limiting the container to be of height 75 by specifying a height. You will need to remove that to prevent it forcing that height. If you added it so there's a minimum height you could use ConstrainedBox with BoxConstraints and a min height of 75.